# CPU support by ghidra

Tags: ida, ghidra

Where can I see all the CPUs supported by Ghidra?

Does Ghidra support more CPUs than IDA Pro?

Answer (score 5):

The supported processors are listed [in the publicly available source code on GitHub](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/tree/master/Ghidra/Processors).

Ghidra and IDA Pro both support quite a wide variety of architectures and processors. It's hard for me to tell which one supports more, and I am not sure how meaningful that kind of comparison is.

For more information, see this presentation and associated materials:

https://github.com/0xAlexei/INFILTRATE2019

It should be noted that adding support for a new processor in Ghidra can be done via Sleigh. Here is an example: [Implementing a New CPU Architecture
for Ghidra](https://guedou.github.io/talks/2019_BeeRump/slides.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the [Ghidra Wiki](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#what-processors-are-currently-supported),

> **What processors are currently supported?**
>
> X86 16/32/64, ARM/AARCH64, PowerPC 32/64/VLE, MIPS 16/32/64/micro,
>   68xxx, Java / DEX bytecode, PA-RISC, PIC 12/16/17/18/24, Sparc 32/64,
>   CR16C, Z80, 6502, 8051, MSP430, AVR8, AVR32, and variants of these
>   processors.

The latest IDA pro supports more than [60 families of processors](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/processors.shtml). IDA does seem to have the upper hand but that gap is quickly closing in as Ghidra being an open-source tool has the community support. IDA though closed source has been around for a longer time so you would also find plenty of user developed processor modules.

Comment: The last sentence is not totally correct: there are plenty of user-developed processor modules for IDA

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Yes I'do agree with that. Updated the answer.